VS Code Pytest won't run individual tests
My VS Code instance (1.94.0) can discover the tests (after modifying the settings.json) and it does run all the tests if I press the "Rerun Tests" button on top of the VSCode Testing Pane (beaker icon).
However,
using the VSCode Testing Pane (beaker icon), when I drill down to the individual tests, it won't run an individual test or run an individual test in debug mode. This used to work and was highly helpful.
here is my settings.json file:
  {
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
      "${workspaceFolder}",
      "--rootdir=${workspaceFolder}",
    ], 
  }

Anyone know how to fix this?

How do you tell it to run an individual test?

If you go into the VSCode Testing pane (the beaker icon), you can drill down to the individual tests. If you hover over one, you will get a play icon to run that specific test (when it works, and it used to).

What does it do instead of running the test if you click it?

Immediatly says "Finish Running Test". but it doesn't actually do it. I know, because the test is in a failed state right now and you also can't add a break point and have it run the individual test in debug.

Try to add "python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true to your settings.json

thanks for the suggestion, but that did not work.

Have you tried to debug test
